# Fragment & MapFragment

Tags: android

## Inconvertible types cannot cast 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

I  have a Fragment in my XML file

```
mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

I got an Error Inconvertible types cannot cast `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` to `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment` while accessing the MapFragment.

How can I Rectify this?

Comment: Are you using it inside a fragment?

Comment: post your xml layout file in the question

Comment: yes.i am using inside the fragment

Comment: Share your xml file where you've added the map fragment

Comment: `<fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapFragment"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />`

Comment: use the `mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` code inside `onViewCreated` method of the fragment.